# How to set a local domain with XAMPP on Windows?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

This is the changes made by me in httpd-vhosts.conf file
  The code for the localhost

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

The code for my domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:800>
        ServerAdmin postmaster@myshop.local
        DocumentRoot "D:\ampp\htdocs\myshop.local\www"
        ServerName myshop.local
        ServerAlias www.myshop.local
        <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local">
        Order allow,deny`enter code here`
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

I need to use myshop.local instead of localhost!!!
    So in hosts i did the following but still can't access it through any
       browser:

```
  127.0.0.1   localhost
     127.0.0.1  myshop.local
     127.0.0.1  www.myshop.local
```

Comment: And what does "still can't access it" actually mean?

Comment: Note that when reconfiguring the hosts in your apache http server you need to restart that server. Also the port configured (800) looks very strange. Sure you do not mean 80 instead?

Comment: port 80 is taken by system so i put 800 .                                                        I can't access myshop.local in my browser and it shows me error 404 , when i ping it (ping myshop.local or  ping www.myshop.local)  packages are sent successful

Comment: And do you specify that port 800 inside the URL you request in the browser? What information does that 404 page offer? Some server signature or the like?

Comment: ok when i paste the address http://myshop.local/  it gives the error: Not Found    HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: Once more: you are using a "funny" non standard port 800 in your configuration. That means a URL `http ://myshop.local` will not be answered by that virtual host you configured, by whatever server "has taken" port 80 as you put it. So either you have to specify port 800 in your URL (`http ://myshop.local:800/`), or you have to sort out whatever it is that "has taken port 80 in your system", stop that from doing something on its own and use the standard http port yourself. Note that this smells a bit of Microsoft: they do such nonsense in their latest versions of the Windows system.

Comment: Ok now i got it !! http://myshop.local:800/  - indicating the port solved kinda  my problem so i must to find the service that is using port 80 . Thanks a lot sir!!!

Comment: If you are really using some Microsoft system, then most likely you have Skype installed, it is well known to bind to that port without asking for permission or anything.